# Can I sign a .exe with a .p7b file?

Tags: security, code-signing, p7b

I have compiled a C++ program with Visual Studio (obtaining a .exe file).

I also have a .p7b file that my company has provided me.

Can I sign my .exe file with this .p7b file? If so, how?

As a note, if I open the .p7b file with a notepad, the text is illegible (for example: `べ٢⬋ĆĄヿ؃̂匰儰ࠆث`).